# how to use the reqMktData from Ibpy properly?

Tags: python, algorithmic-trading, interactive-brokers, ibpy

Hi guys am just starting to work on an Ibpy algorithm and i would like to test it with paper trading first but i have a little understanding how to use the reqMktData to get the last price. I have no problem placing orders but this returns nothing for 25 seconds, Im thinking that it is only to be used during trading hours or maybe am just using it wrong any thoughts?

```
from ib.opt import ibConnection, message
from ib.ext.Contract import Contract
from time import sleep

def my_callback_handler(msg):
    inside_mkt_bid = ''
    inside_mkt_ask = ''

    if msg.field == 1:
        inside_mkt_bid = msg.price
        print 'bid', inside_mkt_bid
    elif msg.field == 2:
        inside_mkt_ask = msg.price
        print 'ask', inside_mkt_ask


tws = ibConnection()
tws.register(my_callback_handler, message.tickSize, message.tickPrice)
tws.connect()

c = Contract()
c.m_symbol = "DATA"
c.m_secType = "STK"
c.m_exchange = "SMART"
c.m_currency = "USD"
tws.reqMktData(788,c,"",False)
sleep(25)
print 'All done'

tws.disconnect()
```

Comment: If the request is being sent successfully, it should return either the data or an error message of some kind. You should make sure you are capturing the error messages. I'm not familiar with Ibpy, but I found how to enable logging here https://github.com/blampe/IbPy/wiki/Getting-Started.  If you are using IBGateway, also check the 'show log' checkbox to see what is happening there (not sure how to view the logs in TWS).

Comment: Hi i have modified it so i can get the error this is what i get: TWS Time at connection:20170801 23:59:20 WET
<error id=-1, errorCode=2103, errorMsg=Market data farm connection is broken:usfuture>
<error id=-1, errorCode=2103, errorMsg=Market data farm connection is broken:usfarm>
<error id=-1, errorCode=2105, errorMsg=HMDS data farm connection is broken:fundfarm>
<error id=-1, errorCode=2105, errorMsg=HMDS data farm connection is broken:ushmds>

Comment: So apparently it is not connecting to usfuture, usfarm, fundfarm and ushmds are those not supposed to be up 24/7 or do i have to pay up to have access?

Comment: They should be up 24/7, you do have to pay for any market data if you haven't already. You have to log in under Account Management -> Manage Account -> Trade Configuration and subscribe there.

Comment: Understood, I guess I will have to finish the application before I can get data. Thank you for the info!

Answer (score 1):

I have try IbPy before and successfully get the data but now I have use Ibapi instead which is more difficult and still can't fully trade in it but it has an adjusted historical price.

So this is my code which you have to tailor what so you want.

1.Get the stock member form Excel

```
from ib.opt import ibConnection, message
from ib.ext.Contract import Contract
from ib.ext.Order import Order
from ib.ext.TickType import TickType as tt
from time import sleep, time, strftime
import datetime
from __future__ import print_function #I'm using 3.x style print
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from math import ceil
import re

xls_file = pd.ExcelFile('xxxx\\Interactive_Broker_trading\\SNP2.xlsx')
df = xls_file.parse('Sheet1')
Ticker = df.iloc[:,1]
all_data = pd.DataFrame(Ticker)
all_data.columns = ['ticker']
all_data['type'] = 'STK'
all_data['exchange'] = 'SMART'
all_data['curr'] = 'USD'
all_data['bidPrice'] =0
all_data['askPrice'] =0
all_data['lastPrice'] =0
all_data['HistoryPrice']=0
```

2.Get the Historical Price by using for loop since my account has a limit of 100 request per moment so I devide it into 8 multiple sessions for S&P 505. Then relogin at each 70 stocks. I can get the total of 505 in 2 minutes.

```
def error_handler(msg):
    print(msg)
def my_callback_handler(msg):
    if msg.field in [tt.BID,tt.ASK,tt.LAST]:
#         from ib.ext.TickType import TickType as tt

        #now we can just store the response in the data frame
        all_data.loc[msg.tickerId,tt.getField(msg.field)] = msg.price
#         if msg.field == tt.LAST:
# #             print('a')
#             print(all_data.loc[msg.tickerId,'ticker'],msg.price)

t = time()
max_amount_per_Iter = 70 #max number per iter to save cost
max_Iter = ceil(len(all_data)/max_amount_per_Iter)
for i in range (0,max_Iter):
    print('====================for : ',i+1,'==========================')
    sleep(1)
    tws = ibConnection(clientId=11+i)
    tws.register(my_callback_handler, message.tickPrice, message.tickSize)
    tws.register(error_handler, 'Error')
    tws.connect()
    all_dum = all_data.iloc[i*max_amount_per_Iter:min((i+1)*max_amount_per_Iter,len(all_data)),:]
    for index, row in all_dum.iterrows():


        c = Contract()
        c.m_symbol = row['ticker']
        c.m_exchange = row['exchange']
        c.m_currency = row['curr']
        c.m_secType = row['type']
        # the tickerId is just the index in but for some reason it needs str()
        tws.reqMktData(str(index),c,'',False)

        sleep(0.2)
    sleep(2)
    print('=========End round : ',i+1,'with time :',time() - t,'==============')
    tws.disconnect()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking it has something to do with the market data subscription within IB itself because I am having a similar problem. I get a TWS Time at connection... returned in the results along with the "market data farm connection" Msg. 
Make sure you have a connection port & clientID established, i.e.:

```
tws = ibConnection(port=7496,clientId=100)
```

Note that 7496 is a common port, but the clientId is anything you wish to specify (within the IB account you are using under File->API->Settings).